# How do you add a field to an IRfcTable using SAP NCo 3.0?

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I can't understand the documentation and really need a concrete example.

I've already created the destination.  Here I define my BAPI:

```
IRfcFunction BapiIncomingInvoiceGetDetail = SapRfcRepository.CreateFunction("BAPI_INCOMINGINVOICE_GETDETAIL");
```

Set my imports, invoke it, and then get my exports - one of which is a table:

```
IRfcTable ITEMDATATable = BapiIncomingInvoiceGetDetail.GetTable("ITEMDATA");
```

I now want to add a field to each item in the table `ITEMDATATable` and set its value so I can reference it later as if it were one of the fields returned by the BAPI.  Can anyone tell me how?

EDIT:  Okay, I've made some progress:

```
RfcFieldMetadata newField = new RfcFieldMetadata("SKU_AMT",0,0,0);
ITEMDATATable.CurrentRow.Metadata.AddField(newField);
ITEMDATATable.SetValue("SKU_AMT",myItemData.SKU_AMT);
```

However, when I try to set the value, I get this error:

> RfcInvalidStateException "Cannot add an element to locked STRUCTURE BAPI_INCINV_DETAIL_ITEM"

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

you can't append columns to the table, the fields are already defined. You need to add a row to the table and populate the fields of that row. This should work (although i can't test it right now):

```
IRfcTable ITEMDATATable = BapiIncomingInvoiceGetDetail.GetTable("ITEMDATA");
ITEMDATATable.Append();
ITEMDATATable.SetValue("SKU_ATM",myItemData.SKU_AMT);
```